# IntelliJ IDEA: Auto detect run configuration like Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

If you open up a class with a `publis static void main(String[] args) {}` method in Eclipse and hit run, then that class will run. If you move to another class with its own main() method and hit run, then that class will run. Is this possible in IntelliJ IDEA? Or will I have to manually change Run configuration every time I want to run something other than the current run configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the class in the Project view and select 'Run YourMainClass.main()'

Alternatively in the text editor with that class open you can right click anywhere in the window and select 'Run YourMainClass.main()'.

Or if you don't want to right click there's a shortcut too (should be displayed in the right click menu - differs by OS)

Doing this will save a configuration in the dropdown as well, so if you go in the edit configurations dialog there you can add vm parameters or any options that need to differ from the default. Configurations created like this have a semi-transparent icon to differentiate them.

Comment: Well that makes it a little bit better. Many thanks!